# Dynamics CRM soap request from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, dynamics-crm

I've been struggling with reading data from a Microsoft Dynamics CRM installation using soap, from Node.js.
I am using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

The code:

```
var soap = require('soap'),
    wsdlUrl = "https://mycrm.domain.com/xrmservices/2011/Organization.svc?singleWsdl",
    username = 'DOMAIN\\username',
    password = 'mypassword';

soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, function(err, client) {
    client.setSecurity(new soap.WSSecurity(username, password));

    // 1. Describe the method
    console.log(client.describe().
        OrganizationService.CustomBinding_IOrganizationService.Execute);

    client.OrganizationService.CustomBinding_IOrganizationService.Execute({
        request : {
          RequestName : 'WhoAmI'
        }
      },
      function(err, result) {
        // 2. Show the output
        console.log(result.body);
      }, null, {
        'Content-Type': "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    });
});
```

The description (1) is this:

```
{ input:
   { request:
      { Parameters: [Object],
        RequestId: 'guid|xs:string|pattern',
        RequestName: 'xs:string',
        targetNSAlias: 'q8',
        targetNamespace: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' } },
  output:
   { ExecuteResult:
      { ResponseName: 'xs:string',
        Results: [Object],
        targetNSAlias: 'q9',
        targetNamespace: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' } } }
```

And no matter what I tried for the parameter, the output I always receive is this:

```
Bad Request
```

Comment: What sort of installation is this? Looks like an IFD in which case I'm wondering about the authentication for starters. Have you turned on tracing for the server and had a look at that? How does the soap-xml look for the request?

Comment: Yes, It's an IFD (On Premise). The authentication is ADFS. (I think) I solved that, since I had other errors initially (401/403 HTTP codes). I don't know how is the soap-xml looking like since I don't know how I can debug that. Unfortunately I do not have access to the CRM server to turn on tracing.

Comment: I haven't done any authentication to IFD with js so I can't really say what might be the issue more than it's a completely different way of working so I doubt that the createclient-line will be working, can't say for sure though.

Comment: The createClient works, the describe on the Execute method (1) works as well, giving the output. What doesn't work is the call to the Execute method. Most probably because I'm not sending the expected input. But what that info is, is beyond my understanding. I know that the SOAP api works from C#, with XML, but in node, it seems to expect a JSON object as input. I also tried with an XML - to no result.